# Residue theorem with winding numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

In my studies, I've been uniquely using the Residue Theorem with no more than a single winding around each singularity. Actually, my professor has never mentioned winding-numbers in the Residue Theorem.

I've been reading discussions about complex integrals, where some people suggest solutions that take winding numbers into account. Is there a general advantage in doing so?

Answer (score 4):

I taught a basic complex analysis class 16 times so far. Initially I did not include the winding number, and restricted the residue theorem to simple closed curves. This is visually satisfactory and usually sufficient for applications, but it gives a hard time for the teacher and the careful student alike. The reason is that one needs to talk about "the interior" and "counterclockwise orientation" of a simple closed curve. However, I found that discussing these concepts *rigorously* is beyond an introductory course. So, after a while, I decided to include the winding number: it simplified the proofs and made the theorem more general. Here is the version I currently teach in my course:

**Residue Theorem.** Let $M\subset\mathbb{C}$ be open. Let $\gamma\subset M$ be a closed curve freely homotopic to a constant curve within $M$. Assume that $f$ is holomorphic on $M\setminus S$, where $S\subset M$ is a discrete subset of isolated singularities of $f$ disjoint from $\gamma$. Then
$$\int_\gamma f=2\pi i\sum_{p\in S} w_p(\gamma)\mathrm{res}_p(f),$$
where the winding number $w_p(\gamma)$ vanishes for all but finitely many points $p\in S$.

Comment: What does freely homotopic mean?

Comment: @VítTuček: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_loop

Comment: @VítTuček: Free homotopy is homotopy without a base point (see e.g. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Homotopy/Free) Fun fact: it took me several years of teaching complex analysis before I learned the proper terminology. For a while I just told my students "homotopy without a base point".

Comment: That's interesting. I've studied complex analysis as part of a course in "advanced mathematics for engineers", where homotopy is never once mentioned. It's nice to extend my knowledge. What I was really wondering is whether winding numbers may help in the evaluation of integrals via the residue theorem.